# subtract last data from first data in ms sql but doing it per day

Tags: sql-server

I have a MS sql query in which I compute for the total kilometer run of my car. To achieve this, I create a query which gets the last data and subtract it from the first data. I can achieve this per day but what I need now is to have it per day but under date range. Here's my code for 1 date filter.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
(
    (
        (SELECT TOP 1 cast(kmrun as decimal(7,2)) as totkm 
            from [MARK_PASSIVE].[dbo].tblkmrun2 
                where PHILTIME BETWEEN '2015-03-02 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-02 23:59:00' 
                    AND PLATENO = 'UUM572' ORDER BY PHILTIME DESC) 
                    - 
        (SELECT TOP 1 cast(kmrun as decimal(7,2)) as totkm 
            from [MARK_PASSIVE].[dbo].tblkmrun2 
                where PHILTIME BETWEEN '2015-03-02 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-02 23:59:00' 
                    AND PLATENO = 'UUM572' ORDER BY PHILTIME ASC)
    )
) as finkm , 
(CONVERT(char(10), PHILTIME, 126)) as NEWDATE 
from [MARK_PASSIVE].[dbo].tblkmrun2 
where PHILTIME BETWEEN '2015-03-02 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-02 23:59:00'
```

Now here's my code for date range and the result as well. The result show the same but it must not be the same since im getting total km run for each day not for the whole date range

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CONVERT(char(10), PHILTIME, 126)), 
( 
    (
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 cast(kmrun as decimal(7,2)) as totkm 
                from [MARK_PASSIVE].[dbo].tblkmrun2 
                    where PHILTIME BETWEEN '2015-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-06 23:59:00' 
                        AND PLATENO = 'UUM572' group by kmrun ORDER BY PHILTIME DESC
        ) - 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 cast(kmrun as decimal(7,2)) as totkm 
                from [MARK_PASSIVE].[dbo].tblkmrun2 
                    where PHILTIME BETWEEN '2015-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-06 23:59:00' 
                        AND PLATENO = 'UUM572' ORDER BY PHILTIME ASC
        )
    )
) as finkm , 
(CONVERT(char(10), PHILTIME, 126)) as NEWDATE 
    from [MARK_PASSIVE].[dbo].tblkmrun2 
        where PHILTIME BETWEEN '2015-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-06 23:59:00'
            ORDER BY NEWDATE DESC
```

here's the result for the date range

[image]

and here's the expected result

[image]

the problem with my query for date range is that it is computing the whole date range, getting the first data from 1 and last data from 6.

Kindly help me re configure my sql query for date range.

Thanks

Data for March1

[image]

Data for Mar2

[image]

Data for Mar3

[image]

Data for March 4

[image]

Data for March 5

[image]

Data for March 6

[image]

result may vary since i limited the data to 5 only.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data we can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DECLARE @startDate  DATE = '20150301'
DECLARE @endDate    DATE = '20150306'

;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        FirstPhilTime = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(PhilTime AS DATE) ORDER BY PhilTime ASC),
        LastPhilTime = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(PhilTime AS DATE) ORDER BY PhilTime DESC)
    FROM tblkmrun2
)
SELECT
    CAST(PhilTime AS DATE),
    FinKm = MAX(CASE WHEN LastPhilTime = 1 THEN KmRun END) - MAX(CASE WHEN FirstPhilTime = 1 THEN KmRun END)
FROM cte
WHERE
    PhilTime >= @STARTDATE
    AND PhilTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ENDDATE)
GROUP BY CAST(PhilTime AS DATE)
```

Comment: It returns negative answer on some dates.

Comment: @Dodgeball, yes it will if the `kmrun` of the last `PHILTIME` is less than the `kmrun` of first `PHILTIME`.

Comment: tweaked it a little. Thanks for all the help and apologize for the trouble.